# Is it possible to force Fortran compiler to use single precision?

Tags: fortran, precision, gfortran

I have a large Fortran code in which most of the real variable is declared to have double precision by using

```
double precision
real*8
```

And I wonder if it is possible to force the compiler to use single-precision for those variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the compiler that you use. GNU Fortran supports the option `-freal-8-real-4`, which transforms all 8-byte reals to 4-byte ones. For instance, the following program

```
program p

    use iso_fortran_env, only: real64

    real(kind=real64) :: x
    double precision :: y
    real*8 :: z

    print *, sizeof(x), sizeof(y), sizeof(z)

end program p
```

prints

```
                    8                    8                    8
```

but when compiled with `-freal-8-real-4`, the outputs is

```
                    4                    4                    4
```

Other compilers may have different options (or none of such kind).

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: real*8 and real(kind=8) are not exactly the same thing and I suggest to not promote the confusion by just changing what the manual says (it says about kind 8 entities, not 8 byte entities).

Comment: True. After testing, I updated the answer to include also "real*8". This answer is compiler-specific, so I took the liberty of using the fact that all the above datatypes in gfortran are 8-byte.